# Multivariable Calculus Distance

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Four towns wish to build a radio station. Suppose that the towns are located at (0, 0), (7,0), (0, 8) and (9, 9) on a square grid.

At what point (a, b) should the station be located to minimize the sum of the squares of the distances from each town to the station?

Is there a certain equation i should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeking $(x,y)$ such that:

$D(x,y) = (x-0)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (x-7)^2 + (y-0)^2 + (x-0)^2 + (y-8)^2 + (x-9)^2 + (y-9)^2 = 275 -32 x + 4 x^2 -34 y + 4y^2$

is minimized.

So take the derivative of $D$ with respect to $x$ and to $y$, set each to zero and solve:  $(4,17/4)$.

[image]